# Export D3 Layout force to png

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, svg, export

I am currently working on a project in which I need to export the image of its SVG created from the d3.js.

I searched on the internet, tried several methods but nothing works. My "Force Layout" is not recognised while the beige frame appears to him. I do not understand.

```js
var svg2 = document.querySelector('svg');
var img = document.querySelector('img');
var canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');

// get svg data
var xml = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(svg2);

// make it base64
var svg64 = btoa(xml);
var b64Start = 'data:image/svg+xml;base64,';

// prepend a "header"
var image64 = b64Start + svg64;

// set it as the source of the img element
img.src = image64;

// draw the image onto the canvas
canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(img, 0, 0);

function dlCanvas() {
  var dt = canvas.toDataURL('image/png'); // << this fails in IE/Edge...
  dt = dt.replace(/^data:image\/[^;]*/, 'data:application/octet-stream');
  dt = dt.replace(/^data:application\/octet-stream/, 'data:application/octet-stream;headers=Content-Disposition%3A%20attachment%3B%20filename=Canvas.png');
  this.href = dt;
};
document.getElementById('dl').addEventListener('click', dlCanvas, false);
```

```html
HTML
   <!-- <div id="graph"></div>--><!-- La visualisation, c'est le "div" a gauche, cf. script "main.js" -->    
    <div id ="graph">
     <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="500" width="1050"> 
       <rect class="canvas" width="100%" height="100%" fill='#f5f5f5'></rect>
     </svg>
   </div>
      Image <img></img>
   <canvas width="1000" height="500"> </canvas>
```

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jzXro.png)

Comment: From your screenshot it looks like you are trying to generate the PNG before the force layout has finished "ticking" (drawing).  Try running your image generation code on the [end event](https://github.com/d3/d3-force/blob/master/README.md#simulation_on).

Comment: I just tried to put the export to the end but it does not change anything, always the same result.
Note that the graph is not static since I am asked the posibility to move the nodes.
I also tried to put the export part in another javascript file but it does not change anything ...
I start programming so it is not obvious. I tried to look for examples. Simple examples work but I have not found anything with anything "dynamic" ...